# Why do double newlines and not single newlines work when writing ouptut in code chunk in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

A little while ago I was trying to figure out how to print a newline in my `knitr` output. I searched around and tried a few things, but none of them worked until I used double newlines, aka `\n \n` instead of `\n`. An example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<echo= F>>=
opts_chunk$set(echo = F,
               message = F,
               warning = F,
               comment=NA,
               width=60)
@

<<results='asis'>>=
cat("a line \n")
cat("another line \n")
@

<<results='asis'>>=
cat("b line \n \n")
cat("bnother line \n \n")
@

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

My question is why this works.[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LaTex you need to have a double-newline in order to start a new line (if you are not using some other command that does that for you). Since you are using `'asis'`, your output is directly interpreted as LaTex code.

Comment: By double newline do you mean `\\`? So each `\n` is interpreted as a single backslash? If so, wouldn't `\n \n \n \n` then cause two newlines, which as far as I can see it does not?

Comment: `\n` is a newline, and `\n\n` is a double newline (when printed with `cat()`).  By default LaTeX will only output one newline, but you can increase the default spacing with something like `\setlength{\parskip}{10pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}`, which adds a +/- 1 pt margin for better page layout (automatic). If you want two newlines, look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208443/49538 for some different ways of doing this. Remember that in R you have to specify `"\\\\"` to produce a literal `\\ ` output in TeX.